# Referencing values from on sharepoint list into the edit form of another sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a sharepoint list that contains the following information [list1]:

- Resource Name [People or Group]
- Project [Choice]

I have another list that contains the following info [List2]:

- Resource Name
- Project
- Date of leave

I am writing a powerapps for the user to apply for a leave and data must be updated in list2, In the powerapps form, the Resource Name should be a dropdown of only the 'Resources' present in list1 [Display Name]. The 'Project' field must populate the project of the 'Resource' selected from list1.

I have set the following properties of DataCardValue of 'Resource Name' in the form to:

```
Items= Choices(list1.'Resource Name') 
Value= DisplayName
```

I have also set the following properties of the 'Resource Name' card in the form to:

```
Update=DataCardValue.Selected.DisplayName
```

No errors are indicated in powerapps, however when i am previewing the app, nothing is being listed in the dropdown of 'Resource Name'. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: during debugging/developing phase do you get results with list1.'Resource Name'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `items` property of dropdown control to:

```
Distinct(list1, 'Resource Name'.DisplayName).Result
```

Then change `Value` to:

```
Result
```

It should show you the options in dropdown control.